# Ubuntu: exit sudo after a bash command?

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I have Ubuntu 10.04. Certain operations in the Terminal application or operations require me to type `sudo [whatever command]` and my password.  I have noticed the effects of `sudo` last for awhile; five minutes or so.

How can I explicitly exit `sudo` and go back to being me at the command prompt?

Comment: Hi user455276.  You might have better luck at http://superuser.com or http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
sudo -k
```

Note that you're not running `sudo` to need to exit it, rather sudo remembers the last time you authenticated and doesn't require re-authentication if that's recent enough.  This command will reset timestamp to the epoch.  You can change the timeout value in the system configuration file: `man sudoers`.

Comment: I can't vote you up because I am only a "1" but I would. Thanks!